# C - Deleting a node in a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, hashtable, nodes

I'm working on a delete function in my code. I want to delete the `key, value` pair within the node and free the space allocated to it. I'm not sure how to approach this so that the following nodes shift into the right place (not sure how to word it, hope you know what I mean). Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "symTable.h"
#define DEFAULT_TABLE_SIZE 61
#define HASH_MULTIPLIER 65599

/*Structures*/
typedef struct Node
{
    char *key;
    void *value;
    struct Node *next;
} Node_T;

typedef struct SymTable
{
    Node_T **Table;
    int tablesize;
    int counter;
} *SymTable_T;

/*Global Variables*/
int tablesize = DEFAULT_TABLE_SIZE;
int counter = 0;

/*Create function to show how memory is allocated*/
SymTable_T SymTable_create(void)
{
    SymTable_T S_Table;
    S_Table = malloc(sizeof(SymTable_T *) * DEFAULT_TABLE_SIZE);
    S_Table->Table = (Node_T **) calloc(DEFAULT_TABLE_SIZE, sizeof(Node_T *));

    return S_Table;
}

/*Hash Function*/
static unsigned int hash(const char *key, const int tablesize)
{
    int i;
    unsigned int h = 0U;

    for (i = 0; key[i] != '\0'; i++)
        h = h * tablesize + (unsigned char) key[i];
    return h % tablesize;
}

/*Delete Function*/
int symTable_delete(SymTable_T symTable, const char *key)
{
    Node_T *new_list;
    unsigned int hashval = hash(key, DEFAULT_TABLE_SIZE);

    free(new_list->key);
    free(new_list->value);

    //here is where I am stuck, how can I make it so the nodes following the one deleted go to the right space?
}
```

Comment: Like @pwilmot mentioned. Start at the top of the table and iterate it until the next node has the key. That you want to delete. Copy that out. Point the next node to the next node of the key node. Then free the key node memory.

Comment: To find if the next node holds that key, would it be something like `if (strcmp(key, new_list->next->key) == 0)`? I'm not sure how to point to the next node's key.

Answer (score 2):

With a singly linked list you have

A -> B -> C

if you want to remove B then you need to make

A -> C

The only way to do this is to get the parent of B and update its pointer which means either

1. You need to add a pointer from a node to its parent ( aka use a doubly linked list )
2. You iterate over the list until you find a node where the child pointer is set to the node you are removing and then you update the pointer to instead point to child.child